# How to create a calendar object with a time-zone

Tags: java, android, datetime, android-calendar, android-date

I need to create a calendar object instance(with the current time) with the same timezone as

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1383128400000,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,
zone=America/New_York,
firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=9,WEEK_OF_YEAR=44,
WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=30,DAY_OF_YEAR=303,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,
DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,AM_PM=0,HOUR=6,HOUR_OF_DAY=6,MINUTE=20,SECOND=0,
MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(c.getTimeZone()+" milliseconds: "+c.getTimeInMillis());

    c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    System.out.println(c.getTimeZone()+" milliseconds: "+c.getTimeInMillis());
```

Note: Everything in Java is in GMT.  so 'now' in my time is the same milliseconds in your time.  What do w/ it after that is whatever you want to do with it.